# Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Parameter format not correct -

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, flutter, dart

Good morning to every body. I got this error when trying to run a code.
excuse my english i am francophone. pleae help me solve this problem

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
error: error reading C:\Users\utilisateur\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\20.0\89507701249388e1ed5ddcf8c41f4ce1be7831ef\guava-20.0.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading C:\Users\utilisateur\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\20.0\89507701249388e1ed5ddcf8c41f4ce1be7831ef\guava-20.0.jar; error in opening zip file
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\BackgroundTaskRunner.java:7: error: package com.google.common.util.concurrent does not exist
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
                                        ^
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\BackgroundTaskRunner.java:8: error: package com.google.common.util.concurrent does not exist
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture;
                                        ^
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\BackgroundTaskRunner.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
  public <T> ListenableFuture<T> runInBackground(final Callable<T> task) {
             ^
  symbol:   class ListenableFuture
  location: class BackgroundTaskRunner
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java:23: error: package com.google.common.base does not exist
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
                             ^
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java:24: error: package com.google.common.base does not exist
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
                             ^
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\BackgroundTaskRunner.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    final ListenableFuture<T> future = runInBackground(task);
          ^
  symbol:   class ListenableFuture
  location: class BackgroundTaskRunner
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\BackgroundTaskRunner.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
    final SettableFuture<T> future = SettableFuture.create();
          ^
  symbol:   class SettableFuture
  location: class BackgroundTaskRunner
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\BackgroundTaskRunner.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
    final SettableFuture<T> future = SettableFuture.create();
                                     ^
  symbol:   variable SettableFuture
  location: class BackgroundTaskRunner
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java:247: error: cannot find symbol
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(hostedDomain)) {
             ^
  symbol:   variable Strings
  location: class Delegate
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-4.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java:454: error: cannot find symbol
              String scopesStr = "oauth2:" + Joiner.on(' ').join(requestedScopes);
                                             ^
  symbol: variable Joiner
10 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 30s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: My connection is good. But i dont understand what you mean by that. Please can i have more details.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this should work:

Step 1: Run `flutter run --verbose`

If that doesn't work after running the above command run `flutter run --pub --hot` and it should work.